Does 1-2mm gap in shower tile warrant inspection for water damage?
The shower tile in our rental property has a 1-2 mm gap along the side. This is a rental, so we (the owners) don't really know when in the past 2 years this happened since the tenants didn't say anything before they left.
We're getting conflicting advice from different property managers and handymen about whether this needs an inspection for water damage. Some claim that the gap is large enough that water easily get in. Some claim that there is often waterproofing behind the tiles anyway, so no worries about damage.
Does this warrant an inspection, or just a reapplication of caulk and grout?


Both are right till proven wrong.  The landlord should know what is behind that tile, and since water damage can get expensive, they should be made aware of it.

FYI, that's not a "crack". It's an enlargement of the normal grout gap. It likely indicates swelling of the wood framing due to moisture. Your question is subjective, though--one person's warranted is another's meh.

I would look below for signs of water leaking where it should not be.
And +1 to what @isherwood commented — water is definitely going through that gap, but it is (your) judgement call whether or not to start tearing things apart to see what is really going on underneath. That depends a bit on whether you are renting (your responsibility ends with reporting the problem), or the owner.

Thank you. I'm the owner trying to decide whether to open it up to inspect or not. How big of a job is it?

Depends if you can inspect from under or from other side of the wall.  Inspecting from the shower will require new tile work.  Inspection cameras only require small holes in drywall/other wall/ceiling coverings.  If the owner, should know if moisture/water controls were used.

If I owned it, I would remove the corner cap tiles to get an idea of what's happening underneath. I suspect that what Isherwood said is accurate - the framing below has swollen due to moisture. However, you won't know until you open it up.
Once the corner cap is off you should be able to see if the tile below has separated as well. You'll have to remove the tiles that are affected but with any luck it may be isolated to what's behind the corner cap. If not, it may require removing additional tiles.
When the tile is off, let it air dry or even use a hairdryer on it.

How big of a job is it to open up, inspect, and re-tile?

Not difficult at all and you'll sleep better once you know. If you are handy you could do it yourself with a little guidance from YouTube. The grout will be fairly easy to match. Be careful removing the tiles however. Tile can be very difficult to match - so don't drop one!
Before you retile, you may have to trim the swollen wood to get it back to size. Sanding will probably do it. But be careful not to knock any of the other tiles off in the process.
If this is beyond what you want to take on, any competent tile person should easily be able to handle it.

Agreed. removing some tile now will give a better picture of what is going on. That information can them drive the decision on how to go forward.  It could be the knowledge that saves an entire shower reno in the future.

As you rent, you should take photos and document that you reported it.
That way any consequences from their remedial work not being timely should be the landlord's problem.
Water can get through smaller gaps than that to cause damage over time. Make sure you keep clear proof that you told them.

Thanks, I'm the owner in this case, so it's really up to me whether to open it up. How big of a job is it to open up, inspect, and re-tile?

A lot easier now than waiting 6 months or a year.
